# Registration Error 400 (Bad Request) & Uncaught (in promise) Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm currently taking Mosh Hamedani's React Course where I have to create a movie rental app and I'm currently in one lecture where I have register a new user. I can send the registration to the database with an email, username and password… But at the same time I keep getting 2 errors:

xhr.js:177 POST http://localhost:3900/api/users 400 (Bad Request) and createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2ZSD.png)

Plus the app won't send me to the Home page after submission. What is causing these errors?

Here’s my user.js code:

```
const auth = require("../middleware/auth");

const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

const _ = require("lodash");

const { User, validate } = require("../models/user");

const express = require("express");

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/me", auth, async (req, res) => {

     const user = await User.findById(req.user._id).select("-password");

     res.send(user);

});

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {

   const { error } = validate(req.body);

   if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

   let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });

   if (user) return res.status(400).send("User already registered.");

   user = new User(_.pick(req.body, ["name", "email", "password"]));

   bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (_err, salt) {

  bcrypt.hash(user.name, salt, function (_err, hash) {

  // Store hash in your password DB.

   user.password = hash;

  });

  });



    await user.save();

    const token = user.generateAuthToken();

    res

     .header("x-auth-token", token)

     .header("access-control-expose-headers", "x-auth-token")

     .send(_.pick(user, ["_id", "name", "email"]));

  });

  module.exports = router;
```

And here’s my registerForm.js:

```
 import React from "react";

 import Joi from "joi-browser";

 import Form from "./common/form";

 import * as userService from '../services/userService'; // Import methods *

 class RegisterForm extends Form {

    state = {

    data: { username: "", password: "", name: "" },

    errors: {}

   };

   schema = {

   username: Joi.string()

    .required()

    .email()

    .label("Username"),

   password: Joi.string()

    .required()

    .min(5)

    .label("Password"),

 name: Joi.string()

    .required()

   .label("Name")

 };

 doSubmit = async () => {

   try {

     const response = await userService.register(this.state.data);

    console.log(response);

    localStorage.setItem('token', response.header['x-auth-token']);

   this.props.history.push("/");

  }

  catch (ex) {

       if (ex.response && ex.response.status === 400) {

      const errors = {...this.state.errors};

      errors.username = ex.response.data;

      this.setState({ errors });

    }

   }



  userService.register(this.state.data);

  };

  render() {

   return (

       <div>

         <h1>Register</h1>

          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

             {this.renderInput("username", "Username")}

            {this.renderInput("password", "Password", "password")}

            {this.renderInput("name", "Name")}

            {this.renderButton("Register")}

        </form>

    </div>

    );

   }

  }

  export default RegisterForm;
```

userService.js:

```
import http from './httpService';
import { apiUrl } from '../config.json';

const apiEndpoint = apiUrl + '/users';

export function register(user) {
    return http.post(apiEndpoint, {
        email: user.username,
        password: user.password,
        name: user.name
    })
 }
```

Comment: Could you add the code of the `userService`, to which route you post exactly?

Comment: Okay I just did.

Comment: Hm okay, seems correct - my posted answer was wrong, therefore I've hidden it (prevent confusion). You receive a `400` error, which your server sends in 2 cases: the `validate(req.body)` function fails or the user is already registered. Can you debug, if `validate(req.body)` works as intended?

Comment: So I debugged it and the only error I got was "Error: Cannot find module 'walker'"